# AWS boto3 Cognito Invalid Access Token Error

Tags: boto3, amazon-cognito

I have a Python lambda function processing an API request from a user to change their password. The API for change_password is as follows

```
response = client.change_password(
    PreviousPassword='string',
    ProposedPassword='string',
    AccessToken='string'
)
```

My question is what should I use to populate the AccessToken?
I have tried the user's token obtained at login (and passed in the event). I have tried the assumed role's credentials:

```
    session = boto3.Session()
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    accessKey = credentials.access_key
```

Unfortunately neither work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK - in order to help anyone else as dumb as me... I was using the Cognito IdToken not the AccessToken (as is clearly stated in the docs - RTFM).
Not sure I really understand when to use each one, but using the AccessToken generated by cognito.initiate_auth() (i.e. login) works just fine!

Comment: fwiw, the access token is for you or anyone else in your aws organization.  The cognito token is for some third party which uses your aws setup but is not part of your organization.  Think of a restricted access to your aws hosted webapp to unknown third parties.